What is PS1 prompt \[\e]0; vs \[\e]2; , it looks like one is for title name of tab, one is for title name of windows
here is my ps1
does someone know documents about this?
export PS1='\[\e]0;YYY@\h:\w\a\]\[\e]2;XXX\W\a\e[32;40m\]\[\e[36;40m\]$?\[\e[31;40m\]\D{%d}\[\e[35;40m\]\D{%H%M}\[\e[36;40m\]\W\[\e[32;40m\]>\[\e[0m\]'



I suggest to consult the Bash Prompt HOWTO, that should cover all the bells and whistles.

@markgraf, but does it cover the difference between \e]0; and \e]2;? Where? If it does, you might consider posting an answer describing the difference along with references to the documentation.

For reference, the \e] prefix is often called "OSC" in documentation (while \e[ is "CSI").

\e]0; (OSC 0) begins a sequence that sets both the terminal's window title and icon title – the latter for desktop environments that allow a separate title for minimized or iconified windows, such as MS Windows 3.11.

\e]2; (OSC 2) sets only the window title (and \e]1; OSC 1 would set just the icon title).

Not to be confused with \e[0m (CSI 0 m, aka SGR 0) which resets all text formatting.


Both OSCs can end with either \e\\ (ST) or \a (BEL), the latter is nonstandard but also common. So \e]0;YYY@\h:\w\a is the whole sequence.
To see the difference between the two on your system, you can try e.g. commands like this:
printf '\e]0;Both titles\a'; sleep 5
printf '\e]1;Icon title\a'; sleep 5
printf '\e]2;Window title\a'; sleep 5

(The sleep commands are there so you can see the changes one by one if you copypaste the whole deal in one go.)
The outermost \[ ... \] in the prompt are specific to Bash; they're not part of the sequence itself, but tell the shell's Readline library that the sequences are zero-width and don't move the cursor when printed, so that it would correctly know how wide the prompt is and how line-wrapping should behave when editing long multi-line commands.

http://web.archive.org/web/2020if_/http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html
https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html


What is the point of this && sleep 1h here?

@KamilMaciorowski: So that the results of the example command remain visible for a while before OP returns to their shell prompt (which otherwise would immediately override the title with its regular "user@host:cwd").
